# Creating XML document using titanium

Tags: ios, xml, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am unable to find any examples or pre-defined XML methods to create XML document using titanium. Do any body have an example or methods to create XML document using Titanium [Appcelerator]. Any suggestions on this ?

Thanks
Ranjith

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start your search with Titanium's documentation:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_XML_Data

Or with the whole namespace dedicated to manipulating XML, Titanium.XML:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML